Shared code block followed by different block for mutually exclusive predicates
What is the best way to express this code? (It was difficult to phrase in words)
if cond1 or cond2:
    # shared code
    if cond1:
        # cond1 code
    else:
        # cond2 code

The above obviously duplicates the check
if cond1:
    # shared
    # cond1
elif cond2:
    # shared
    # cond2

This repeats the shared code
I am writing an implementation of Dijkstra's, the question arises within the relax function
def dijkstra(s):
    
    def relax(w, v, edge_cost):
        w_via_v = distance[v] + edge_cost
        if w not in distance:
            distance[w] = w_via_v
            toexplore.push(w)
        elif w_via_v < distance[w]:
            distance[w] = w_via_v
            toexplore.update(w)
    
    distance = {s: 0}
    toexplore = PriorityQueue([s], sortkey=lambda v: distance[v])
    
    while not toexplore.is_empty():
        v = toexplore.popmin()
        # Assert: v.distance is distance(s to v)
        # Assert: thus, v is never put back into toexplore
        for w, edge_cost in v.neighbours:
            relax(w, v, edge_cost)

Another alternative is
def relax(w, v, edge_cost):
    if w not in distance:
        distance[w] = ∞
        toexplore.push(w)
    w_via_v = distance[v] + edge_cost
    if w_via_v < distance[w]:
        distance[w] = w_via_v
        toexplore.update(w)

But this unnecessarily pushes a node into the priority queue only to update it again

It depends on context and what makes the most sense reading.
In general, for most use cases I can think of, I would favor:
if cond1 or cond2
  shared

if cond1
  logic1

if cond2
  logic2

Because every unique if condition (i.e. the whole condition that is part of that if) tends to be the meaningfully readable indication of why you want to hit that block.
Additionally, it's usually better to avoid repetition with code blocks instead of evaluations (if you have to choose and can't do both), because code blocks are lengthier to write and more likely to introduce bugs by forgetting to alter each copy/pasted version when making changes.

There is no singular best way to write such an if-elif statement where some of the paths have partially shared code. It depends too much on the specifics of the code you are writing.
What can be said in general is that your first priority is to write code that can be easily understood. After that you can start looking at principles like DRY and, for example, refactor duplicated blocks of code into a function.
The reasoning behind DRY is that when you have to make a change/correction to duplicated code, you have to make the change in N spots and you probably forget K of them. But that reasoning only holds if the process of removing duplicates does not introduce extra complexities to the code that make it harder to understand and maintain.
In your specific example of the relax function, your first version with the duplicated distance[w] = w_via_v is much easier to understand and check against the official description of the algorithm. The duplicates of that line are also close enough together that you instantly see all instances that need to be updated if/when a change is needed.
Even though there is a duplication in it, that version is way better than the one where you tried to remove the duplication.

"your first version with the duplicated distance[w] = w_via_v is much easier to understand" - well, looking at the 2nd version, I am not convinced there should be a duplicate assignment in the first version; I guess the correct version would be distance[w] = ∞, like in the 2nd version. Or do you see a reason why w_via_v is set to ∞ in w_via_v = distance[v] + edge_cost?

@DocBrown, your comment nicely illustrates why the first version is better. If you carefully (mentally) trace the execution of both versions, you will see that in both cases distance[w] is either left alone or set to `distance[v] + edge_cost'. Specifically, it is never left at infinity in the second version.

You  are right, and I should have more sleep.

In the general case I would favor:
if cond1:
    # shared
    # cond1 code
elif cond2:
    # shared
    # cond2 code

Simply because the logic is easier to follow - it's obvious what conditions need to be true to execute each block.
You are likely asking the question, because you are worried about the duplicated shared code. In this specific case, it's a one line assignment, as such I wouldn't worry about the duplication - it is unlikely it is going to confuse anyone.
If the shared code was large/larger I would consider pulling it out into a method. That may or may not be a practical option, if pulling out a method isn't practical (results in a mess) then frankly my best advice is to try writing the code a couple of different ways and pick the one you think is more readable.

It's always a good idea to avoid repeating identical blocks of code.

To avoid repeating the computation for cond1 and cond2, you can always compute both conditions once, assign them to flags and then check the flags repeatedly for no extra cost.
And if the code in shared is nontrivial, you should probably move it into a subroutine so that the duplication is minimized.


Always is a strong word - I might go as far as saying you should always consider alternatives that avoid duplication, but I would not say that avoiding duplication always improves the code.

@DavidT That's what I mean with "good idea". Eliminating duplication will increase readability and maintainability, but there can be other concerns that are more important in a specific case.

I would sight this question as an example of when the readability of the code is reduced by removing the duplication (it is not "always a good idea"), I recognize that in this case the code is trivial and as the code gets more complex reducing duplication often helps, but I not willing to concede it always helps.

It depends how much is duplicated. If 1 line is duplicated but it keeps the logic easier, duplicate it. If 100 lines are duplicated pay for slightly harder logic instead. And look at what tools your language has (obviously function calls, but also closures and finally/defer statements).
